# Batch file using If statement and keyboard input

Tags: batch-file, if-statement, user-input

A slightly late Happy New Year to everyone, hope you had a good one.

I'm trying to create a batch file that will take keyboard input and then either launch a program based on that input or display an error message if the option entered isn't valid.  But it's not working.  Here's what I've got so far:

```
ECHO OFF
set /p %environment%=Connect to Live or Dev?:

IF %environment% = "Live" 
(
C:\Windows\System32\runas.exe /user:live\someuser /netonly "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\110\Tools\Binn\ManagementStudio\Ssms.exe"
) 
ELSE IF %environment% = "Dev" 
(
C:\Windows\System32\runas.exe /user:dev\someuser /netonly "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\110\Tools\Binn\ManagementStudio\Ssms.exe"
) 
ELSE 
(
ECHO "Invalid Option"
)
```

I've tried it with and without the % round the variable but it didn't work.  Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Hope you can help.

Cheers

Alex

Comment: remove the `@echo off` to see what happens: 1) look, how your `if`-line is translated. 2) the `(` has to be on the same line than the `if` 3) `) else (` has to be on one line

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Here's some code to get you in the right direction. I tested this with a .cmd file in Windows 7.

```
ECHO OFF
SET /p environment="Connect to Live or Dev?"
IF /i "%environment%" == "Live" GOTO live
IF /i "%environment%" == "Dev" GOTO dev
ECHO Invalid Option
GOTO end
:live
ECHO "Live!!!!"
goto end
:dev
ECHO "Dev!!!"
:end
PAUSE
```

Answer (score 4):

```
ECHO OFF
set /p "environment=Connect to Live or Dev?:"

IF "%environment%"=="Live" (
    ....
) ELSE IF "%environment%"=="Dev" (
    ....
) ELSE (
    ....
)
```

1 - In `set` command, the name of the variable on the left side of equal sign does not use `%` signs. `%var%` sintax is used to retrieve the value of the variable.

2 - The operator to test for equality is `==` or `EQU` (see `if /?`)

3 - In the `IF` command, the same quoting should be applied to both sides of the equality operator. If not, values will not be considered equals

4 - The commands / block to execute when the `IF` command condition is true, must start in the same line that the IF, so starting parenthesis can not be in the next line

5 - The `ELSE` must continue the `IF` block and precede the start of its own block. Close parenthesis of the `IF` and starting parenthesis of the `ELSE` must be in the same line.